# Dynamically creating elements with data from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to populate my page with divs filled with data I gather from my recordData.json file.

Each record in the JSON file should have an element like:

```
<div class="card text-center bg-dark cardBorder" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/1984.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">1984</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Van Halen</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JSON file is formatted as:

```
"recordData": [
        {
          "name": "Let's Rock",
          "artist": "The Black Keys",
          "genre": "Rock",
          "imagePath": "images/Let's Rock.jpg"
        },
        {
          "name": "Brothers",
          "artist": "The Black Keys",
          "genre": "Rock",
          "imagePath": "images/Brothers.jpg"            
        }, //and so on
```

I have this jQuery function:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("recordData.json", function(data) {
        var html = '';
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            html += '<div class="card text-center bg-dark cardBorder" style="width: 18rem;">';
            html += '<img class="card-img-top" src="'+value.imagePath+'" alt="Card image cap">';
            html += '<div class="card-body">';
            html += '<h5 class="card-title">'+value.name+'</h5>';
            html += '<p class="card-text">'+value.artist+'</p>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
        });
    $("#recordDiv").html(html);
    });
});
```

I have the function placed in a script tag in the body, but nothing is populating on the page. Could anyone let me know if I am missing something or what may be going wrong here? P.S. this is my first post so go easy on me :)

Comment: Could you possibly put it in a codepen so I could play with it? Nothing is jumping out right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see an html element with id "recordDiv" in your html file

```
 $("#recordDiv").html(html);
```

Make sure the id of the html element is correct

Plus it does not look like you are accessing the key of the array in the json file "recordData"

Comment: Apologies. `<div id="recordDiv" class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center p-2">` is where the script tag is located.

Comment: console.log in your loop to make sure it is actually running

Comment: Did the console and it is not. It's throwing me "jQuery.Deferred exception: $.getJSON is not a function TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function". Verified the syntax with documentation and it looks correct, though.

Comment: git rid of the your loop logic and debug **calling the getJSON function** and **printing the file data** to see if the file if being read in the first place

Comment: also make sure are accessing the array with `data.recordData` instead of just `data`

Comment: Made that last change and updated to the full jQuery version (apparently slim doesn't support the getJSON shorthand) and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parentheses on the first line of your `$.each` block. Remember to use the chrome / browser devtools console to quickly spot syntax errors like this one.

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("recordData.json", function(data) {
        var html = '';
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            html += '<div class="card text-center bg-dark cardBorder" style="width: 18rem;">';
            ...
```